# Disable Satellizer Popup Window Title Bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, oauth, satellizer

I'm using the satellizer plugin for authentication to Facebook.  The problem I'm having is the popup that the facebook login is using has the title bar and everything.  I need to remove the title/menu bar, etc.  It should be a modal window.  I can't figure out how to configure that using the facebook login.

I'm using the default setup:

```
$authProvider.facebook({ clientId: '<ID>' });
```

Can I specify a setting here?  What would that be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your popupOptions:

```
location: 'no', toolbar: 'no'
```

so it should look like this:

```
popupOptions: {
  location: 'no',
  toolbar: 'no',
  width: 400,
  height: 600 
}
```

However - it's probably a good idea to do this outside satellizer module. Otherwise it will be wiped out on module update.

I hope that helps.